# a mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc fails on "invalid module name" in deep level dependencies. How to skip this problem?

Tags: java, maven

I would like to update my javadoc dependencies : I have the `JDK 11` installed on command line.
It fails for some with a *Can't extract module name from ... '...' is not a Java identifier.*", related I think, to the Java 9+ module feature, used by up to 0.001% of the Java projects in the world.

`mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc | grep -e 'Invalid module name'`

```
[INFO] Can't extract module name from jsr-275-1.0-beta-2.jar: jsr.275: Invalid module name: '275' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spark-core_2.11-2.4.4.jar: spark.core.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from chill_2.11-0.9.3.jar: chill.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spark-launcher_2.11-2.4.4.jar: spark.launcher.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spark-kvstore_2.11-2.4.4.jar: spark.kvstore.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spark-network-common_2.11-2.4.4.jar: spark.network.common.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spark-network-shuffle_2.11-2.4.4.jar: spark.network.shuffle.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spark-unsafe_2.11-2.4.4.jar: spark.unsafe.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from json4s-jackson_2.11-3.5.3.jar: json4s.jackson.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from json4s-core_2.11-3.5.3.jar: json4s.core.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from json4s-ast_2.11-3.5.3.jar: json4s.ast.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from json4s-scalap_2.11-3.5.3.jar: json4s.scalap.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from scala-xml_2.11-1.0.6.jar: scala.xml.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.9.8.jar: jackson.module.scala.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spark-tags_2.11-2.4.4.jar: spark.tags.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spark-sql_2.11-2.4.4.jar: spark.sql.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spark-sketch_2.11-2.4.4.jar: spark.sketch.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spark-catalyst_2.11-2.4.4.jar: spark.catalyst.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spark-mllib_2.11-2.4.4.jar: spark.mllib.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.1.0.jar: scala.parser.combinators.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spark-streaming_2.11-2.4.4.jar: spark.streaming.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spark-graphx_2.11-2.4.4.jar: spark.graphx.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spark-mllib-local_2.11-2.4.4.jar: spark.mllib.local.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from breeze_2.11-0.13.2.jar: breeze.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from breeze-macros_2.11-0.13.2.jar: breeze.macros.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spire_2.11-0.13.0.jar: spire.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from spire-macros_2.11-0.13.0.jar: spire.macros.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from machinist_2.11-0.6.1.jar: machinist.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from shapeless_2.11-2.3.2.jar: shapeless.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from macro-compat_2.11-1.1.1.jar: macro.compat.2.11: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from byte-buddy-1.9.12-javadoc.jar: byte.buddy: Invalid module name: 'byte' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Can't extract module name from byte-buddy-agent-1.9.12-javadoc.jar: byte.buddy.agent: Invalid module name: 'byte' is not a Java identifier
```

Of course, I can't ask *jsr*, *spark*, *chill*, *json4s*, *scala*, *jackson*, *breeze*, *spire* *machinist*, *shapeless*, *macro-compat*, *byte-buddy* project teams to correct these projects.

Is there a way to ask `maven` to skip this problem ?

Comment: It is kind of tricky how to solve this, because classifiers can be used for valid java modules, but never for javadoc, so that's a special case. First of all I wouldn't execute this with the `-Dclassifier=javadoc`, the plugin takes care of finding the matching javadocs per dependency.